# Looking up a value in a range and checking a second value in the row above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a calendar that uses dynamic, dependent drop-down menus.
Each column represents a date.
In each column, there can be up to 30 evaluations written over 3 rows:
- Subject
- Group - Teacher
- Type of evaluation

At the very bottom, there is a second table that counts how many evaluations each group will have that day. However, groups are sometimes split (eg.: group 301 will split into Music and Dance classes). So in that second table, group 301 will have a total for the Dance group, and another for the music group.

If they all followed the same schedule, it'd be easy to simply have a formula like: =COUNTIF(E$4:E$113,"*301*").

I could use a REALLY long formula along the lines of =COUNTIF(E$4:E$113,"*301*")-COUNTIFS(E4:E4,"*301*",E3:E3,"*musique*")-COUNTIFS(E7:E7,"*301*",E6:E6,"*musique*")-....., but with 30 entries, this doesn't seem efficient at all.

I'm looking into INDEX, MATCH, OFFSET, etc... but can't seem to pin down the right formula. The goal of it would be to look for the group number (eg: 301), see if the previous row holds the keyword I want to subtract from that total (eg: remove 301 music's evaluation from the total for group 301 taking dance class).

I can't use VBA, because teachers will be using the online version of this form, so I have to stick to formulas.

Any help would be appreciated (file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19QZr6o-0NTYEurG5jaO-BpK29N9r5iMp)).

Comment: I can see that you have put down some COUNTIF formulas in the second table. Can you please confirm that those formulas in your sample file were **NOT** getting the results you want? If so can you please provide a new sample file filling out Monday courses from P1 to P6, manually enter the expected counts in the second table, and clearly state the logic behind each count in your second table? Otherwise it would be too broad to guess what you are expecting to count in the second table.

Comment: I was in the middle of filling it the Monday column to help contributors find the solution, when I realized I found an alternative to what I was asking. Hence this thread can be closed. Thanks for the thought!